# How to make this jQuery function more generic (use class without losing specific positioning)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make this jQuery function more generic?
I would prefer if #draggable was .draggable and the function could determine what .draggable was clicked, and then handle that element untill unbind.

Thanks!

```
function drag(){
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $('#draggable').css({
           left:  e.pageX,
           top:   e.pageY
        });
    });
};
function drop(){
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
    $('#draggable').css({
        left:  $('.box').position().left,
        top:   $('.box').position().top
    });
    alert('Well Done! ^^')
};

<div id="draggable" onclick="drag();">
    <!-- Image -->
</div>
<div class="box" onclick="drop();">
    <!-- Placeholder -->
</div>
```

source:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/794168/

Comment: Why don't you use draggable/droppable from jQuery UI?

Comment: You are using jQuery *and* inline event handlers? Why?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I want don't want to drag and drop, but I want to click and drop.

Comment: I'm sure you can start dragging on click.

Comment: @FelixKling: How else can I make the div follow the mouse without holding the button?

Comment: No, what I meant is that you should use jQuery to bind the event handlers, like `$('#draggable').click(drag)`. That is much cleaner and jQuery makes it so easy.

Answer (score 0):

For the first step you could add a selector function for your function parameters:

```
function drag(selector) {
    $(selector) ... your code
}
```

The next step is to create a jQuery plugin to encapsulate this behavior. I've written many of these if you need advice.

Comment: Seems interesting to add this behaviour in a jQuery plugin. I'm reading this page http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring but any examples would be welcome since I have very little jQuery experience. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've created the following trying to build a custom jquery plugin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/795993/
But it's not working. can you give me some advice? I would appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You are on the right track but you have no context to your instance. See here -> http://www.jasonsebring.com/tutorial-how-to-create-jquery-instance-aware-plugin   as I wrote this a bit ago. I can give more advice in a couple of days no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI is not the best way to learn, imo.

I modified your code a bit :

```
$(function(){
    var currentDrag;
    $('.draggable').click(function(){
        currentDrag = $(this);
        $(document).bind('mousemove.drag', function(e){
            currentDrag.css({
                left:  e.pageX + 1,
                top:   e.pageY + 1
            });
        });
    });

    $('.box').click(function(){
        if(currentDrag){
            $(document).unbind('mousemove.drag');
            currentDrag.css({
                left:  $('.box').position().left,
                top:   $('.box').position().top
            });
            currentDrag = "";
            alert('Well Done! ^^')
        }
    });
});


<div class="draggable">
    <!-- Image -->
</div>
<div class="box">
    <!-- Placeholder -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the answer! check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5zVB8/8/

the draggables use classes and the script knows which draggable is which!

the only problem is that if you click-drop a second item after click-dropping the first. an onclick handler for drop is on the drop "box" which is covered by the first draggable.

you didn't mention anything about hiding the first box after dragging to the box.

EDIT: added a release function so you can click-drag out the dropped draggable that's in the box to anywhere in the screen.

Comment: The release function is great! do you perhaps know how to pass to the id of the current box to the .box function? so that it places the draggable in the right .box? That would be great! thanks

Comment: updated the fiddle. the script has the variable `elementDragged` which contains the jQuery object of the box that we are dragging - this you can use jQuery functions on it. during dragging, the box is stored to that variable. during release, it is reverted to `null` - meaning we are not dragging anything. if you want to make a script to check which box is it, do it before nulling it. example, i added `alert('dropped '+elementDragged.attr('id'));` just before turning it to null.

Comment: awesome, I'll take a look at it. the event.stopPropagation is not recognised by FF though..

Comment: `return false` does the same exact thing actually. but place it in the last part of the block of code which it should be in. here's a fiddle using `return false` instead of `event.stopPropagation()` - http://jsfiddle.net/5zVB8/9/

Comment: thanks, but I found the problem, firefox does not recognise event.stopPropagation(), but does recognise e.stopPropagation() thanks! Guess this Question is finally solved